# Where to download publish profile for my Azure SQL project?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database, publish

When publishing services and sites to my Azure account, I just fetch the publish profile and use it. It works like a charm. However, I can't find any profile to publish my database project. I can **create** a local file with extension *publish.xml* but it doesn't work when uploading.

I've tested a bunch of different settings but I get all kinds of errors (0, 25, 40 etc.) and to be honest, I can't see me getting through any time soon.   :)

I also tried to download the simple project and copy the XML-file from there. However, when I attempt to publish that way, I get an error about VS not being able to connect to the server after 21 seconds.

Where can I download the file generated by my Azure account? (Please note that it's not the *pubxml* files I'm talking about here.)

I've found [this article](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/continuous-deployment-windows-0) but on my account, it looks like this, instead.

[image]

Comment: Just a question, if you set manually the username / password / server it works? Are using SSDT?

Comment: Nope. I tried **first** to set up things manually (I prefer the hard labor). When I failed, I hoped for automatized process to get me there. As of now, I can only runt the deployments scripts directly in the web client for Azure, in the portal. I'm not using SSDT (I think) - just the facilities in the VS.

Comment: I found: http://architects.dzone.com/articles/continuous-deployment-windows-0

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio You "found" the link to the article that I posted in my question, mate. I posted an image of what **I** can see on my screen - there's no such menu... :)

Comment: Ohh really. My bad. Yeah, it's because your are searching the credentials for your database, not for the web site. Take a look at the article. You will publish de website, and set to run the update database.

Comment: The project is strictly a database oriented. There's no page to deploy. The services and web page is deployed from elsewhere. I only have a database project in the current solution and I wish to deploy **that** to the Azure. I've set the deployment platform to SQL Azure but it gets me the errors described in the question...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38188/discussion-between-thiago-custodio-and-konrad-viltersten)

Answer (score 1):

first of all : did you open firewall access toyour database server? you need to enable this thorugh themanagement portal on SQL level or through the powershell / cli tools. for SQL there's no such thing as a publishingsettingsfile

and connecting happens through a SQL based user and password credential. (this user and password was set during sql database setupe, and can be reset and found in the portal)

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've enabled the firewall to allow connections at one place in the web client. I believe that's the only opening requirement needed, right? The user I'm trying to connect as has the same credentials as the ones that I specify when logging in via the web client, so these should be correct.